# Pasting data between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

> Run-time error 1004

Hi all so I'm having this problem. I wrote this code on my laptop1 and it didn't work. I thought I wrote it well, so I emailed the file to my other laptop2 and it ran perfectly.
Both run the newest excel version 64bit. I can't seem to troubleshoot the problem. IT IS THE EXACT SAME FILE. maybe a computer setting? I'm dumbstruck

```
 For r = 6 To 84 Step 39
        For c = 3 To 36 Step 3
             Sheets("xyz").Cells(r, c).Resize(31, 3).Copy
             With Sheets("Report")
                 .Activate
                 .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                 .Paste Link:=True
             End With
             Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next c
    Next r
```

Same file on other computer and it works, whats the problem?

Comment: Though I can't see why (nor can I recreate): it may be worth confirming the references are linked and working on the system that's throwing the error?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @TimWilliams .paste Link=true

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try without the activate/select:

```vb
    For r = 6 To 84 Step 39
        For c = 3 To 36 Step 3
             Sheets("xyz").Cells(r, c).Resize(31, 3).Copy
             With Sheets("Report")
                 .Paste Destination:= .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Link:=True
             End With
             Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next c
    Next r
```